# Options to get around 404s in my selenium webdriver tests?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am running my selenium webdriver tests in parallel at the method level. Due to the high number of access times, I see a lot of intermittent 404s, as a result of which my tests are failing. I was browsing through solutions for catching these 404s and came across quite a few HTMLUnit and proxy options. All seem nice. But before delving into any of these options, i wanted to pick your brains concerning the following requirement which im not sure is possible?

Requirement:
If a 404 is encountered during a test run(reading around, im convinced theres no way for webdriver to do this currently?), how do i get past/around it to still make my test pass?
The only way i can think of is to refresh the page till the 404 goes away? and then continue? Not sure if there's a simpler way of doing this though?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to get your web application fixed or reduce the number of running instances of Selenium.
If the web application does not work, why should tests pass?

Note that **404** are "not found" errors, see this [List of HTTP status codes on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) why do you get them instead of a **500** or **503** error code??